# Is there any other good way to convert an algebraic expression into a specified form?

Tags: function-construction

The original algebraic formula is:

```
((-a^2 + b^2) k)/Sqrt[(1 + k^2) (b^2 + a^2 k^2)]
```

To convert to:

```
(a^2 - b^2)/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + b^2/k^2 + a^2 k^2]
```

The parameter range is:

```
{a>b>0,k<0}
```

Is there any other method that I am using?

```
((-a^2 + b^2) k)/Sqrt[(1 + k^2) (b^2 + a^2 k^2)] /. 
 a_.*k/(Sqrt[b_*c_]) :> -a/(Sqrt[Apart[Expand[b c/k^2]]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
e1=((-a^2+b^2) k)/Sqrt[(1+k^2) (b^2+a^2 k^2)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
e2=(a^2-b^2)/Sqrt[a^2+b^2+b^2/k^2+a^2 k^2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The leaf count for e1 is 32 and for e2 is 35. So simplify is not going to work as is.

You basically want to divide the numerator and denominator of `e1` by `-k` but the trick is that you want to move the `k` inside the sqrt in the denominator.

One way could be

```
termToDivideBy = -k;
Simplify[Numerator[e1]/termToDivideBy]/(Denominator[e1]/.Sqrt[x_]:> Sqrt[Expand[x/termToDivideBy^2]])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What you did is also fine solution. I do not think there will be a solution to this that is builtin and one needs to do custom solution for this, since are you asking for special transformation.